# TypeScript conditional type based on parameter requires double specification of parameter value?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to condition the return value of a function on the value of the function's parameter.

This works:

```js
type Result<T> = T & { extra: boolean; };
type CondResult<T, P> = P extends true ? Result<T> : T;

function build<T, B extends boolean>(someParam?: B): CondResult<T, B> {
  return {} as CondResult<T, B>;
}

const r1 = build<{ a: string; }, false>();
const r2 = build<{ a: string; }, true>(true);
console.log(r1); // Just a.
console.log(r2); // a, extra
```

See it in the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsAPAFQHxQLxQygDIoBvKCAD2ACcBDALigCMB7V5COgOwG4oAvrwBQoSFADCrbgBM4SVJgA0UAAo58qitQiz4UWomgB+WAhTpsUJhhHCAZom4BjYAEtpLRG+QzlUACFtYF0ZfTYOLm4sAAp4VgBbCFU6egTjJgCASiYpWXkLfwCcUmEoKBoIYEQabjIBKDp9PLlzRQwVYpEBYWFnaXhgCoBGPC8fP3JGKEGaN24Ac34BFXs6ZHgIWKyRfu5BioAmMeZvXzQppln5pcEVQy2Yh52+gciAOmRWBZiaYZ2oAB6QFQABSiAOdHer32Hy+PxohwBwMaKiotDoQA).

The problem is that I had to specify the second type parameter when calling `build()`.  I even had to do this even for the `false` case, when I can call the function without arguments.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This has little to do with conditional types; TS doesn't support *partial type argument inference* as requested in [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).  The usual workaround is currying as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wOrq7W).  See the linked q/a for more info

Comment: Ah, thanks!  I'm a lucky boy because I can actually reduce the type parameters to 1 (the parameter type) because this function is inside a factory function that receives the first type parameter.  I naively simplified my issue to just the final function without realizing I was tripping myself.